# Getting build error when trying to implement a comparator for sorting map data type?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am trying to build a comparator for a map to be used with sort() function.
consider a map object called right with an id and coordinates as the basic member. I am trying to sort the elements of this object with euclidean distance. below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
namespace NONBCG_DATA_ALGO
{
    template<typename T>
    T distance(std::vector<T> P1, std::vector<T> P2 , int dim)
    {
        if ((typeid(T) == typeid(int)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(double)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(float)) )
        {
            float accum = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
            {
                accum += pow((P2[i]-P1[i]),2);

            }
            return sqrt(accum);
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Type should be either int,double or float");
        }
        

    }
    
    template<typename T>
    class distance_compare_asc_comp_id_2D
    {
        public:
        distance_compare_asc_comp_id_2D(std::vector<T> ipt):Pt(ipt){};
        bool operator()(const std::pair<int,std::vector<T>>& p1,const std::pair<int,std::vector<T>>&p2)
        {
            
            if ((typeid(T) == typeid(int)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(double)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(float)) )
            {
                
                return NONBCG_DATA_ALGO::distance<T>(Pt,p1.second,2) < NONBCG_DATA_ALGO::distance(Pt,p2.second,2);

            }
            else
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Type should be either int,double or float");
            }

        }
        private:
        std::vector<T> Pt;
    };


};

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
   std::map<int,std::vector<double>> right;
   right.insert(std::pair<int,std::vector<double>>(1,{2,8,3}));
   right.insert(std::pair<int,std::vector<double>>(6,{2.5,5.4,3}));
   sort(right.begin(),right.end(),NONBCG_DATA_ALGO::distance_compare_asc_comp_id_2D<double>(std::vector<double>{0.0,0.0}));

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error while building

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from /tmp/wxeRdlKRUn.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<double> > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<NONBCG_DATA_ALGO::distance_compare_asc_comp_id_2D<double> >]':
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4899:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<double> > >; _Compare = NONBCG_DATA_ALGO::distance_compare_asc_comp_id_2D<double>]'
/tmp/wxeRdlKRUn.cpp:70:122:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<double> > >' and 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<double> > >')
 1968 |     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
      |               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The issue isnt with the comparator per se, the issue is you're trying to sort a map. You cannot do that. A map's key's are immutable attempting to sort will just fail.

Comment: `if ((typeid(T) == typeid(int)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(double)) || (typeid(T) == typeid(float)) )` this entire line can and should be a static assert. No need for a runtime exception when you can catch this at compile time instead.

Comment: A `std::map` is ordered by its key, and can't be reordered. Perhaps a vector of (key, value) pairs would be more suitable?

Comment: Several things wrong here 1) You cannot sort a map, instead you pass the comparator type as a third template argument when the create the map, the map is then automatically sorted according to the comparator 2) Comparators work on the key of the map, not on the key/value pair, 3) `operator()` in a comparator must be declared `const`

Comment: (john, Borgleader ,molbdnilo) Thanks for the suggestion will try to pass the comparator as the third argument of the template during creation or will convert it to a vector to do the process.

Comment: @siva_uchiha What is the `int` you now use as a _Key_ in the `map`? Is it part of the object? It looks like you should swap the _Key_ and _Value_ or use a `std::set` and possibly drop that `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

molbdnilo's suggestion of using a vector of pairs fits perfectly for my usage. Thanks, everyone for the help!